# list comprehension returns error while try / except doesn't

Tags: python, python-3.4

I'm a python N00b and am attempting to convert this working function into a list comprehension:

```
def sums_lists(list1, list2)
     try:
             sums_list = []
             for index in range(14):
                 sums_list.append(list1[index]+list2[index])
         except:
             pass
```

The code above works, but when I convert this into list comprehension format like so:

```
sums_list = [(list1[index]+list2[index])for index in range(14)]
```

it returns an error `Unsupported operand type(s) for + int and str`

The data its working with is personal data records, address, job, income etc., so ints and strs.

I don't understand why it functions in the try except loop and not as a comprehension?

Comment: The **whole point** of `try: except:` is to suppress errors (a bare `except:` is very bad practice, by the way). What did you expect would happen? Can you provide inputs and expected and actual outputs?

Comment: thanks .. for that.  it's rows of data from a website in the format of: "39, State-gov, 77516, Bachelors, 13, Never-married, Adm-clerical, Not-in-family, White, Male, 2174, 0, 40, United-States, <=50K".  Output is to generate 2 lists with an element by element sum of the two lists.  It's just for an assignment I'm working through at the mo'

Comment: **Edit the question**. What is the output of your first snippet?

Answer (score 0):

a single except will prevent any except to be raised.

To fix your code, try this:

```
sums_list = [(int(list1[index]) + int(list2[index])) for index in range(14)]
```

or

```
sums_list = [(str(list1[index]) + str(list2[index])) for index in range(14)]
```

Probably one of those list have a string instead of a integer, and string and ints can't concatenate by the `+ operator`